# How do I get transactionId and amount from an outputId

Tags: shimmer, rust

With `let output = client.get_output(&output_id).await?;`
I get the output like in this example https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/iota.rs/how_tos/get_output/

How do I get `transaction_id` and `amount`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output id already contains the transaction id, so you can also get it from there

```
let transaction_id = output_id.transaction_id();
let transaction_id = output.metadata.transaction_id;
let output_amount = Output::try_from_dto_unverified(&output.output)?.amount();
```

Credit goes to clever and Thoralf on the IOTA&Shimmer Discord